# Is there a way to auto-reply to blocked SMS messages?

Tags: sms, sms-blocking

I wish to block numbers from text messaging me, but with an auto-reply. I tried every single suggestion here and other places and for one reason or another, they would not do this for me. The built in spam filter, or call reject, won't reply to text messages that are being blocked in it's spam list. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Avant.

Comment: I tried to answer other question on here but did not know any answers

Comment: See if the description of [Auto SMS Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tmnlab.autoresponder) fits your goal. I think it's also doable using **Tasker** but that's just a theory.